# ConcurrentModificationException while saving large collections in Hibernate

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I have the following problem:

I have an application which sends a DatabaseJob to a queue in a separate thread, when an entity should be saved in the database. While the queue has jobs, this worker thread takes the first job from the queue and uses Hibernate to save it. In general this works quite fine.

The problem I have, appears when trying to save large collection (1000+) entries. It can happen that the collection is modified while Hibernate tries to flush it to the database, resulting in the following `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
2014-09-01 10:37:57,301 ERROR [DatabaseManager] [Thread: database-message-queue] Hibernate - Unhandled Exception during saving
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:711)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:734)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.getSnapshot(PersistentSet.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionEntry.afterAction(CollectionEntry.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
```

All collections I use are made safe for concurrent access by using `Collections.synchronizeXXX`, but for iterating it has to be synchronized manually.

Is there any way to synchronize the collection access by Hibernate respectively using the thread-safe iterator? I already tried to use `org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType`, which didn't work either.

Otherwise I think I may have to copy the entities before adding them to the database queue, but I hope there is an easier way to do so.

Thanks very much in advance,
Benjamin Gaunitz

UPDATE 1 -> relevant code block (Exception handling removed for simplicity)

```
private void processHibernateSaves() {
    if (!savesHibernate.isEmpty()) {            
        Iterator<DatabaseJobEvent> jobIter = savesHibernate.iterator();
        while (jobIter.hasNext()) {
            DatabaseJobEvent job = jobIter.next();
            Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            for (PersistentObject obj : job.getObjects()) {
                if (obj.isSavedInDatabase()) {
                    session.update(obj);
                } else {
                    session.save(obj);
                }
            }
            tx.commit(); //<-- Error is thrown at this point
            session.clear();
            for (PersistentObject obj : job.getObjects()) {
                synchronized (obj) {
                    obj.setSavedInDatabase(true);
                }
            }
            job.setExecuted(true);
            jobIter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

`PersistentObject` is not the collection itself it contains the collection as a field.

Comment: Show us the code where you persist the collection

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Collections.synchronizeXXX is not enough.
Use java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList instead.

Comment: Also better forbid modifycation collections during saving.

Answer (score 0):

Java don't provide CopyOnWriteHashMap implementation but see if you can use jersey impl

https://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/jersey-client/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/client/impl/CopyOnWriteHashMap.java

You need to pass its clone to hibernate API

Or write your own implementation
http://concurrently.blogspot.in/2007/07/implementing-copy-on-write-hashmap-in.html

Comment: In java present ConcurrentSkipListMap